# Flask JSONEncoder set ensure_ascii to False

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, encoding, flask

I'm working on a small flask app in which I want to return strings containing umlauts (in general German special characters, e.g 'ß'). As the default `JSONEncoder` in flask has `ensure_ascii=True`, this will always convert my string

```
Hauptstraße 213
```

to this:

```
Hauptstra\u00dfe 213
```

My first approach was to just create a very basic custom `JSONEncoder`

```
class NonAsciiJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NonAsciiJSONEncoder, self).__init__(kwargs)
        self.ensure_ascii = False
```

If I use this, by setting

```
app.json_encoder = NonAsciiJSONEncoder
```

my `return jsonify(...)` will actually return the string containing 'ß'.

However, as `ensure_ascii` is an attribute of the default Encoder, I thought it might be better to just change it by setting it to `False`

```
app.json_encoder.ensure_ascii = False
```

This will actually set the property to False which I checked before returning. But somehow, the string is still returned without 'ß' but with `\u00df`.

How can this be, as all I'm doing in my custom Encoder, is setting this attribute to `False`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are setting a *class* attribute when altering `app.json_encoder.ensure_ascii`, which is not the same thing as an *instance* attribute.

The [`JSONEncoder.__init__` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/json/encoder.py#l101) sets an instance attribute to `True`, as that is the default value for the `ensure_ascii` argument. Setting the class attribute won't prevent the `__init__` method from setting an instance attribute, and it is the instance attribute that wins here.

You could just have your subclass set the argument to `False`:

```
class NonASCIIJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['ensure_ascii'] = False
        super(NonASCIIJSONEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: ah, thanks a lot. I had been under the impression that app.json_encoder points to an object, which is obviously not the case

Comment: @LawrenceBenson: it is a class, yes, not an instance, because it is passed into the [`json.dumps()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) as the `cls` argument.