# How to make Flask/jsonify output accented characters instead of \u escapes?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, flask-sqlalchemy

This example code outputs JSON to the browser, but escapes the accented characters in the output. I've been trying to make these characters human-readable using jsonify, but have had no success.

From file: project.py

```
# jsonify the one widget in testr001.db
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/testr001/<int:id>/JSON/')
def WidgetJSON(id):
    widgets = session.query(Widget).filter_by(id=id).all()
    return jsonify(MyWidgets=[w.serialize for w in widgets])
```

Output:

```
{
  "MyWidgets": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "m\u00f4use"
    }
  ]
}
```

Flask and SQLAlchemy are quite new to me; it's possible I've missed something in the documentation and in the SO posts I've been reading for the past couple of days.

The full (small but working) example code is at https://gist.github.com/jazcap53/ca1463dacc4104165510

I'm using Flask 0.10.1, SQLAlchemy 0.8.4, Python 2.7, on a Vagrant Ubuntu 14.04.3 vm.

This is for an introductory online course. The course project implementation does not support Unicode, but I built my version from the ground up to handle a utf-8 charset.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to worry about this. Both `"m\u00f4use"` and `"môuse"` are valid ways to put that string into a JSON file. A JSON parser will turn these escapes back into the unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you @roeland for your reply. I'm still wondering, though, whether there's a way to make the JSON file itself more friendly to human eyes.

Comment: I don't know, often JSON libraries have an option for that. You will probably find it in the flask documentation.

Comment: @jazcap53 use an extension for your browser that will render it nicely for you. https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter for Chrome works well.

Comment: Thank you @AlastairMcCormack. I've installed json-formatter and it works as advertised. Even allows access to the raw as well as the formatted JSON, which is very nice.

Comment: related: [Flask JSONEncoder set ensure_ascii to False](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32341363/4279)